# use javac and java to excute class file with extern classes under other directory

Tags: java, javac

I try to use javac to compile my javafile `javac Main.java -cp ./lib HelloWorld.java` and I got this `javac: file not found: HelloWorld.java`
here is my java sourcefile:
Main.java under ./

```
    import lib.*;

    public class Main 
    {
        public static void main (String []args)
        {
            HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld ();
            System.out.println (hw.getMsg ());
        }
    }
```

and HelloWorld.java under ./lib

```
package lib;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public String getMsg ()
    {
        return "HelloWorld!";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well yes - you're asking it to compile `HelloWorld.java`, not `lib/HelloWorld.java`. The file `HelloWorld.java` (relatively to the current working directory) doesn't exist...

Comment: use proper path specified: `/lib/HelloWorld.java ` not with a space

Comment: Thanks all of you guys! I finally excute the Main class. Details in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738343/import-class-file-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be

```
javac Main.java lib/HelloWorld.java
```

Your attempt fails for a couple of reasons:

- the `-cp lib` (if required) should be before the sourcecode pathnames
- the classpath is not used to find source files; it is for finding compiled files.

In this case, setting the classpath to `./lib` is wrong for another reason.  The directory `lib` actually corresponds to the package name for the `HelloWorld` class.  If the classpath was `./lib`, then `java` and `javac` would look for the compiled version of `HelloWorld.java` in

```
   ./lib/lib/HelloWorld.class
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I hava misunderstood the meaning of `-cp`.Thanks for your time and patience!!

Comment: To clarify the second bullet (which is entirely correct), it's used to find compiled files that your code imports which the compiler needs to see to make sure you are using the API properly.  I probably said that badly, but you get the picture.